# How to not get cmake variable mangled during install?

Tags: cmake

Please see below minimal example:

```
project(sample)
add_library(Foo foo.cpp foo.h)
target_link_libraries(Foo PUBLIC "-framework myweirdframework")
target_compile_options(
  Foo PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:-iframework${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/my/weird/framework/path>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:-iframework${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/my/weird/framework/path>
)
target_link_options(
  Foo PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:-iframework${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/my/weird/framework/path>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:-iframework${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/my/weird/framework/path>)

install(EXPORT FooTargets DESTINATION lib/cmake/Foo)
install(
  TARGET
  Foo
  EXPORT
  FooTargets
  ARCHIVE
  DESTINATION
  ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
```

I have to link to a framework that is in a non standard location, and I was able to get it to compile and link properly in the build tree, however I am having trouble for the install. If I `make install` and look at the installed FooTargets, in the `INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS` and `INTERFACE_LINK_OPTIONS` of the imported Foo, the `CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT` variable got mangled to the path of my local Xcode, which obviously is not portable, I need the `CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT` variable to not get mangled. However, I attempted things like

```
target_compile_options(
  Foo PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:-iframework${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/my/weird/framework/path>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:-iframework\${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/my/weird/framework/path>
)
target_link_options(
  Foo PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:-iframework${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/my/weird/framework/path>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:-iframework\${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/my/weird/framework/path>)
```

and the `INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS` of the imported Foo becomes `-iframework\${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/my/weird/framework/path`, which doesn't work because of the `\` in it, how can I specify the `INSTALL_INTERFACE` in `target_compile_options` and `target_link_options` so that in the installed FooTargets, the `INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS` and `INTERFACE_LINK_OPTIONS` of the imported Foo will show precisely `-iframework${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/my/weird/framework/path`?